# How to write rendered template output to file?

Tags: scala, twirl

I'm using [Twirl](https://github.com/playframework/twirl) in a non-play sbt project, and defined a template:

**hello.scala.html**

```
<h1>Welcome hello world</h1>
```

It generates a Scala file containing the following code:

```
package html

import play.twirl.api._
import play.twirl.api.TemplateMagic._

import io.github.freewind.feverblog._

/**/
object hello extends BaseScalaTemplate[play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable,Format[play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable]](play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat) with play.twirl.api.Template0[play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable] {

  /**/
  def apply():play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable = {
      _display_ {
        Seq[Any](format.raw/*1.1*/("""<h1>Welcome hello world</h1>"""))
      }
  }

  def render(): play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable = apply()

  def f:(() => play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable) = () => apply()

  def ref: this.type = this
}
```

The return type of `render()` and `apply()` is `play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable`. How can I convert it to a String so I can write it to a file?

Comment: @Jacek, thanks for editing all the English errors, I really love that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable` is just a type alias for `play.twirl.api.Html`, which has a `toString` method.

i.e.

```
views.html.hello().toString
```